# Using .html() to clear previous random string not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, for-loop, random

I am writing a short function that appends a random string that is equal in length to a given word. For example, if you input the word 'hello' it would return a random string that is 5 letters long.

This part works as expected. However, I am using `$('output').html("");` to overwrite the last random string. I have used this for other functions before and it has worked as expected but it does not here. I have tried moving it around the function to see if it has something to do with the order of the function but it's not deleting the previous random string.

What am I doing wrong?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/oo5eLbpu/)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var text = "";
var possible = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').on('click', function () {

        var value = ($('#input').val());
        for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        };
        $('#input').val("");
        $('#output').html("");
        $('#output').html(text);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the `.html()` part. The problem is that your var `text` is never getting reset.

For reference - http://jsfiddle.net/oo5eLbpu/2/

Updated answer will be as follows

```
var possible = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').on('click', function() {
        var text = ""; // moved the variable inside the click handler
        var value = ($('#input').val());
        for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
                possible.length));
        };
        $('#input').val("");
        $('#output').html("");
        $('#output').html(text);  
    });
});
```

Additionally, you can remove the following line from code

```
$('#output').html("");
```

As the line beneath it sets the content of the element.

For reference - http://jsfiddle.net/oo5eLbpu/4/

For documentation - http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 3):

You need also reset variable `text`,

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
   text = '';
   // your code 
});
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/oo5eLbpu/1/)

or move `text` variable from parent scope to `onlick` handler

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
   var text = '';
   // your code 
});
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/oo5eLbpu/3/)

Also you don't need

```
$('#output').html("");
```

because you set content

```
$('#output').html(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try 
`$('#output').empty();`

From: https://api.jquery.com/empty/